# MassTransit Kafka Add producer at runtime

Tags: masstransit

Is there any way we can add a producer from our controller dynamically. We get the topic name at runtime and would need to add this using rider.AddProducer<ClassA,ClassB>() and then retrieve its instance using GetRequiredService<ITopicProducer<ClassA,ClassB>>().
I have gone through the documentation and this question, but couldn't find the answer.
[Kafka Producer with MassTransit - IBusInstance has not been registered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63493491/kafka-producer-with-masstransit-ibusinstance-has-not-been-registered)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't currently a way to add Kafka topic producers dynamically – they must be declared during rider configuration.

> This seems like a reasonable feature request, you could submit one [here](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/discussions/new).

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing your question and relating it to my problems, I created a wrapper on the MassTransit Kafka integration to handle its producer dynamically. You can see it at this address:

[github library](https://github.com/mortezarezaei68/dynamic_masstransit_KafkaIntegration)